# How can I debug an indefinite HTTP request in Chromium/Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, console, request, chromium

I am troubleshooting an issue where I believe an HTTP request is waiting an indefinite amount of time for a response.  In Chromium's developer console, the Network tab does an excellent job at displaying completed traffic and events, but not current ones (that I can see).

How can I debug a lingering HTTP request using Chromium's developer console?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue for quite sometime. On the developer tools Network tab, I can see that all requests match the response on my server log and none is waiting. I even tried to shutdown the server while it is happening, and it still waits indefinitely.

This doesn't happen with Firefox and Opera so I'm inclined to say that it's a chrome bug.

Added: I have also noticed that when I close chrome then open it again, the issue disappears.